# Unable to Create map entries in Hazelcast

Tags: java, maven, in-memory-database, hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast v2.5 and Maven plugin in Eclipse . I tried running an example program in Eclipse which creates 3 map entries in the ABCD namespace . When I run my code in Eclipse it shows this WARNING message

```
Feb 07, 2013 12:08:23 PM com.hazelcast.impl.ConcurrentMapManager
WARNING: [192.168.1.36]:5702 [dev] Caller -> RedoLog{name=c:ABCD, redoType=REDO_TARGET_UNKNOWN, operation=CONCURRENT_MAP_MERGE, target=null / connected=false, redoCount=53, migrating=null
partition=Partition [227]{
}
}
```

This keeps on Iterating till the redo threshold exceeds.

```
Feb 07, 2013 12:08:42 PM com.hazelcast.impl.LifecycleServiceImpl
WARNING: [192.168.1.36]:5702 [dev] [CONCURRENT_MAP_MERGE] Redo threshold[90] exceeded! Last redo cause: REDO_TARGET_UNKNOWN, Name: c:ABCD
com.hazelcast.core.OperationTimeoutException: [CONCURRENT_MAP_MERGE] Redo threshold[90] exceeded! Last redo cause: REDO_TARGET_UNKNOWN, Name: c:ABCD
    at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$ResponseQueueCall.getRedoAwareResult(BaseManager.java:640)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$ResponseQueueCall.getResult(BaseManager.java:627)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$RequestBasedCall.getResultAsBoolean(BaseManager.java:437)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$ResponseQueueCall.getResultAsBoolean(BaseManager.java:544)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.ConcurrentMapManager$MPut.mergeOne(ConcurrentMapManager.java:1758)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.ConcurrentMapManager$MPut.merge(ConcurrentMapManager.java:1747)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.LifecycleServiceImpl$1.run(LifecycleServiceImpl.java:143)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.executor.ParallelExecutorService$ParallelExecutorImpl$ExecutionSegment.run(ParallelExecutorService.java:212)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.ExecutorThreadFactory$1.run(ExecutorThreadFactory.java:38)
```

Why does this occur ?

Please Help.!

Comment: have you simply tried adding the hazelcast-2.5.jar file (& client jar file) and tried the example?  I am not suggesting that you do not try Maven.

Comment: I imported all the jar files including the Hazelcast-2.5.jar . It runs OK on my "eclipse with Maven" but I don't get the required output in my command prompt terminal. Should I do anything else for it to display the map entries in my command prompt. And why I am doing all this is I am trying to have a Java API for Hazelcast. Suggest me an alternative if any please.!

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following just to get started with a barebones Java class (I suggest you go through a more detailed tutorial as it might be more useful - I have not gone over accessing Hazelcast service):

1. Specify the map in the hazelcast.xml file as follows:

   ```
      <map name="testMap">     
       <backup-count>1</backup-count>
       <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>
       <max-size policy="cluster_wide_map_size">0</max-size>
       <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
       <merge-policy>hz.ADD_NEW_ENTRY</merge-policy>
       <map-store enabled="true">
       <class-name>models.test.StoreLoadTestMap</class-name>
       <write-delay-seconds>5</write-delay-seconds> 
       </map-store>
       <entry-listeners>
       <entry-listener include value="true"local="false">models.test.ListenerTestMap</entry-listener>
        </entry-listeners>
        </map>
   ```

Once done, you can simply call  the following from your Java app:

```
IMap<String, testObject> testMap = Hazelcast.getMap("testMap");
```

Now, you should be able to put/get values to and from the map as needed.  You can use tcp or multicasting for replication based on your use case (use tcp if possible) and retrieve info from the second map for confirmation of data replication.  Please also understand how data gets replicated across maps.

Hope it helps